# networkx edges return wrong indices

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I started using python and networkx from a few days.
I have an unoriented graph and I try to iterate on the edges incident to a node.

I used

```
print (G.edges)

for i in G.nodes:

    print( G.edges(i))
```

obtaining

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]

[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4)]

[(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]

[(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4)]

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

The edges provided by `G.edges()` have the two nodes reversed in some cases (e.g., for i=1 I have edge (1,0), but it does not exist !! I have only (0,1). Since the graph is unoriented, it is the same edge, but if I try to use it as the index of a vector of the edges it does not work.

I tried

```
for i in G. nodes
...   do something with .... x[e] for e in G.edges(i)
```

Comment: what is your question exactly? `G.edges` removes duplicate representations of undirected edges while neighbor reporting across all nodes will naturally report both directions, according to [networkx doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#graph-reporting).

Comment: My graph is not oriented. I store the  edges returned by G.edges() in an array of variables (I am writing a mathematical model). Retrieving the edges with G.edges(node) I have edges where the two nodes have the reverse ordering than in G.edges(), so they cannot be used as index of my variables. Example: G.edges() = [(0,1), (0,2)] and G.edges(1) returns (1,0) ! Is it possible to have the edges with the two nodes (index) as in the G.edges() list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the list of `G.edges()` to be in both direction

```py
a = [e for e in G.edges]
```

gives you the list of edges `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]` which removes duplicate representations of undirected edges while neighbor reporting across all nodes will naturally report both directions, according to [networkx Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#graph-reporting).

You can either:

**1) duplicate the list by adding edges representation in reversed order**

```py
a = [e for e in G.edges] + [(y, x) for (x, y) in G.edges]
```

which gives you

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 0), (2, 0), (4, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

or; **2) use list comprehension to get edges from `G.edges(i)` like you did:**

```py
b = [e for i in G.nodes for e in G.edges(i)]
```

output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```